# Choosing particular rows from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have performed a group by in the pandas dataframe to see how many rows are there for each location and each date.

```
agg_count = df.groupby(['date', 'location']).count()
```

Now I want to see the rows of this new dataframe that satisfy a particular condition. Say, count is greater than 50. How do I iterate over this huge dataframe efficiently to get those rows?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. Could you post some example DataFrame? If it's just to compute the number of rows, wouldn't `size()` be enough instead of `count()`?, in which case you could do some boolean indexing like `agg_count[agg_count > 50]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this data

```
In [275]: df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20130101, 20130101, 20130102], 'location': ['a', 'a', 'c']})

In [276]: df
Out[276]:
       date location
0  20130101        a
1  20130101        a
2  20130102        c
```

This selects columns that have a count > 1

```
In [277]: df.groupby(['date', 'location']).apply(lambda sdf: sdf if len(sdf) > 1 else None)
Out[277]:
                         date location
date     location
20130101 a        0  20130101        a
                  1  20130101        a
```

Dropping multi-index below

```
In [278]: df.groupby(['date', 'location']).apply(lambda sdf: sdf if len(sdf) > 1 else None).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[278]:
       date location
0  20130101        a
1  20130101        a
```